# Где можно хранить данные во время редиректа?

Tags: php

Есть php-файл, в который отправляются данные посредством ajax. В php-файле происходит валидация и обработка этих данных, но после этого мне нужно сделать редирект на страницу, где мне эти данные в последующем будут нужны. Где мне лучше всего хранить эти данные во время редиректа?

Comment: А какого рода данные? Варианты разные есть, например cookies

Comment: @Станислав простенький json-массив. Я что-то слышал о том, что эти данные можно хранить в php-сессии, но примера, наглядно демонстрирующего это, так и не нашёл.

Comment: ну просто разные массивы бывают, например корзина в интернет-магазине, ее бывают и в куки записывают. А вообще вот: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242346/php-session-lost-after-redirect - если поможет, могу в ответе повторить

Comment: @Станислав спасибо, попробую. Такой вопрос ещё. А если я делаю ajax-запрос к php-файлу, в котором есть редирект через `header('location')`, то редирект сработает? Или всё-таки лучше дождаться окончания работы скрипта и сделать редирект через javascript посредством `window.location`?

Comment: По поводу ссылки выше - забыл уточнить, что там скорее набор советов содержится, так как реальный пример сильно зависит от кода, который ты пишешь. По поводу вопроса в предыдущем комментарии - да, сработает, если верно его сделать - в первую очередь, не выводить ничего никоим образом до посылания хедера

Comment: Да, ну и еще, если нужно потом получить эти данные обратно в некий JS-скрипт уже по новому адресу, и если нет проблем с хранением этих данных в cookies, то установить session.use_cookies в true в php и потом взять оттуда (из куки) данные js-скриптом. Если используете JQuery, можно использовать плагин для него: https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

Comment: но с другой стороны, если условия выше верны, то вообще не нужно ничего городить с PHP и заморачиваться с его редиректом, работате просто через тот же jquery-плагин и для записи куки, и для взятия их оттуда. Опять же, если такой вариант оптимальный, могу вынести это в ответ :)

Answer (score 0):

В сессии им самое место

1. Стартуете сессию вызовом `session_start()`
2. Заполняете массив `$_SESSION[]`
3. Делаете редирект
4. Стартуете сессию вызовом `session_start()`
5. Считываете данные из массива `$_SESSION[]`
6. Если данные больше не нужны - удаляете их из массива

**hello.php**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['hello'] = 'World!';
header('Location: world.php');
```

**world.php**

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['hello'];
unset($_SESSION['hello']);
```

Comment: А как мне правильно изъять содержимое массива `$_SESSION[]`при помощи JS? Можно, конечно, создать невидимый `<div style="display: none">`, засунуть в него данные, запарсить на JS и удалить, но хочется реализовать это всё культурно, без костылей.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin Никак. Это серверный объект. Но ничто не мешает вывести его содержимое на страницу и при помощи JS распарсить вывод

Answer (score 0):

Вам вполне подойдёт localStorage. Переменные этого объекта хранятся на уровне браузера.

```
localStorage.setItem('ключ', 'значение');
localStorage.getItem('ключ');
localStorage.removeItem("Ключ");
localStorage.clear();
```

Всё интуитивно понятно. И вот хорошая, лёгкая статья:

tproger.ru/articles/localstorage/

Comment: не подойдет, поддержки всеми браузерами нет